# Magento 2: edit the cart summary template

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

On the cart page, I have moved the cart *totals* below the cart *products*:

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.items" after="checkout.cart.form"/>
```

I had wrapped the cart products in a Bootstrap panel:

[image]

Now I need to end the panel after the cart totals and all the following elements. So I need to know: What is the .phtml file containing the code below?

```
<div class="cart-summary">
 // More code here
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, I just want to move the cart summary so that my page turns into:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That div with "cart-summary" class is not actually a phtml file. It is a container defined in `checkout_cart_index.xml` like this `<container name="cart.summary" label="Cart Summary Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-summary" after="-">`.

Inside this container you can find some blocks and some of them are rendered using knockout js. If you want to add more code inside that div, just add more blocks inside the container like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
    <block name="cart.summary.custom.block" class="My\Module\Block\Class" template="cart/template.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: So, are you saying that there is no _.phtml_ file  with this code `<div class="cart-summary">
 // More code here
</div>`?

Comment: Yes. as you can see, in the container signature there is a htmlTag property with div value and a htmlClass property with cart-summary value which generates the <div class="cart-summary"></div> element. All the code inside this div is rendered by the blocks defined inside the container in layout file.

Comment: How do I move it inside `<div class="panel-body"></div>`?

Comment: Try to move Bootstrap panel code inside `module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml`. In this way, all the content from cart page will be wrapped, from cart items to summary. There you can decide if you want to wrap the cart when it is empty or not.

Comment: The `<div class="panel-body">` closes too... early and does not include the cart summary.

Comment: In default magento 2 layout, cart summary is located inside `checkout.cart.items` container which has the `with-items` alias so it should work properly... Take a look in your third party modules, they probably changed the location of `cart.summary`.

Comment: Where do I find the `with-items` and `no-items` templates?

Comment: `with-items` and `no-items` are just aliases for containers and they don't have a template. I suggested you to edit the `cart.phtml` template because it's the template of `checkout.cart` block which contains both `with-items` and `no-items` containers according to `module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` layout file.

Comment: I do not want to use custom blocks. I just want to move the cart summary so that my page turns into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um1bH.png) (see screenshot)

Comment: Overriding `module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml` is a clean way to do your task and it will result in something like this: `<div class="panel-body"><div class="cart-container"> {code} </div></div>`. If you want to put your panel-body div inside cart-container will result into a messy code because you'll have to add `<div class="panel-body>` into a template and you'll have to close the `div` inside another template and this is not the best thing.